# Oracle - Exchange child partitions

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

Given two identical tables (CUSTOMER and CUSTOMER_TMP) with the following example structure:

```
create table customer(
customer_id number,
customer_name varchar2(400),
churn_flag number, -- 0 or 1 
active number  -- 0 or 1
)
PARTITION BY LIST (ACTIVE)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (churn_flag)
( PARTITION p_active_1 values (1)
  ( SUBPARTITION sp_churn_flag_11 VALUES (1)
  , SUBPARTITION sp_churn_flag_10 VALUES (0)
  )
,
 PARTITION p_active_0 values (0)
  ( SUBPARTITION sp_churn_flag_01 VALUES (1)
  , SUBPARTITION sp_churn_flag_00 VALUES (0)
  )
);
```

The tables are partitioned by the ACTIVE-flag (0 or 1), whereas each of the corresponding partitions is subpartitioned with the another flag, the CHURN-flag, which also can be 0 or 1.

CUSTOMER_TMP is first populated with the data. CUSTOMER is then to be populated by the EXCHANGE PARTITONS feature.

My question:

Is it save to perform that by the following statements:

```
alter table customer exchange partition p_active_1 with table customer_tmp without validation;
alter table customer exchange partition p_active_0 with table customer_tmp without validation;
```

or do I have to seperately exchange every subpartiton or in other words: does exchange partition automatically exchanges also the underlying subpartitions safely?

Comment: I do wish that Oracle would have an `exchange data` or similar syntax that would allow the data segments of two tables to be exchanged in exactly the same way that `exchange partition` exchanges the data segment of a partition with a data segment of a table. The current implementation is just not flexible enough.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  Is that not just a RENAME?

Comment: @BobC It's close, but renaming would "move" triggers along with the data, and there would be issues of object invalidations, and you might also need to rename indexes, triggers, etc.. It would also require 3 DDL statements instead of 1, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may populate the table partitionwise. To do so define a table with the partitioning structure corresponding to the subpartitioins of the CUSTOMER table

```
 create table customer_tmp_act(
 customer_id number,
 customer_name varchar2(400),
 churn_flag number, -- 0 or 1 
 active number  -- 0 or 1
 )
 PARTITION BY LIST (churn_flag)
   (PARTITION sp_churn_flag_01 VALUES (1)
   , PARTITION sp_churn_flag_00 VALUES (0)
   )
 ;
```

I'm calling the table `customer_tmp_act` to highlite that it contains only active records  `active = 1`.

Fill the table with all active customers, note that the partitions of the TMP table will be filled corectly based on the value of churn.

Example

```
insert into customer_tmp_act values (111,'xxx',0,1);   
insert into customer_tmp_act values (111,'xxx',1,1);
commit;
```

**Status before exchange**

Temporary table with two partitions each one row.

CUSTOMER table is empty.

Than use

```
 alter table customer exchange partition p_active_1 with table customer_tmp_act without validation;
```

to exchange the partition of the CUSTOMER table with the TMP table. All partitions of the TMP table became SUBPARTITIONs of the CUSTOMER table.

**Status after exchange**

The temporary table is empty, the CUSTOMER table active partition, **both subpartition are filled**.

You may verify it with

```
 select * from customer SUBPARTITION (sp_churn_flag_11);
 select * from customer SUBPARTITION (sp_churn_flag_10);
```

**Note** it is your responsibility (as using *without validation*) to provide the correct ACTIVE value in the TMP table - as you diables the validation be Oracle. Otherwise you end with wrong data in wrong partitions.

Repeat the process for the not active customers, you may reuse the same TMP table, but again this time all records must have active = 0.

Also note that in this schema if the CUSTOMER table is not empty before the exchange, you *lose the data*. The data from CUSTOMER are stored in the TMP table after the exchange.

**Troubleshooting**

One caveat in EXCHANGE PARTITION is difference in the column definition
leading to `ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION`

Use following query, it must giv ethe exact same result for both tables:

```
 select   COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH, DATA_PRECISION, NULLABLE 
 from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'CUSTOMER' order by column_id;
```

Comment: So, the exchange partition does not exchange subpartitions, subpartitions must be changed seperately? CUSTOMER must be empty? I thought it would be overwritten.

Comment: @royskatt I added example to make it more clear. Pls read documentation of EXCHANGE PARTITION if there are still problems.

Comment: That doesn't work: SQL Error: ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
14097. 00000 -  "column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION"
*Cause:    The corresponding columns in the tables specified in the
           ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION are of different type or size
*Action:   Ensure that the two tables have the same number of columns,
           with the same type and size. Tables have exactly identical Columns, ,column names, datatyps and dataprecision.

Comment: @royskatt this error is caused by difference in the column definition in the two tables. I updated the answer to show how to detect it

Comment: I would use "user_tab_cols" (in place of "user_tab_columns") as it also list hidden/system generated columns.